# Query to check duplicate record not working in 1 table but working for another table

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a table having a record for last month i.e. January 2018. The table format is as below:

```
D       ||  month  ||  year  ||  No of Sales
Jan-18  ||   01    ||  2018  ||  231
```

Now, I am running a query to query to check for this record but, I am getting no output.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE [year]=left(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(mm,-1,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)),112),4) 
AND [month]=left(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(mm,-1,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)),1),2)
```

The expected output is:

```
D       ||  month  ||  year  ||  No of Sales
Jan-18  ||   01    ||  2018  ||  231
```

This same query is working for another table which has the same structure as 'mytable'. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What are you trying to check? What's your expected output?

Comment: My expected output is the last month's record as shown in the Question.

Comment: Your sample data and expected output are the same. How do we know what are you trying to get? Then give more sample data

Comment: how is data stored for previous month in that another table???

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by more data. The table has 1 record for each month of the past. I need to check if last month's record is there in the table or not. If it is not there, then I would run a separate query to insert the last month's record into the table. What I have mentioned in the question is a situation where the table already has last month's record but the query I am using is not returning this record. I just want to know what is wrong with the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this query. If result is not empty than that means there is a record for last month

```
select
    *
from
    myTable
where
    eomonth(datefromparts([year], [month], 1)) = eomonth(getdate(), -1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Uzi. Would really appreciate if you could help identify the issue with my query.

Comment: Works for me. If you are sure that your query should return a record then problem maybe in your data. Try to change `...where  ltrim([year])=your_expression and ltrim([month])=your_expression`

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct. The only doubt I feel is - there may be some unnecessary spaces in your table rows,

better use trim function

or

update existing records.

Try

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE RTrim(LTrim([year]))=left(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(mm,-1,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)),112),4) AND RTrim(LTrim([month]))=left(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD(mm,-1,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)),1),2)
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you give an example, please?